# ¿Como copiar valores en campos disponibles segun condiciones especificas?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy ajustando las lineas de una macro, la cual debe copiar los valores contenidos desde la columna E hasta la columna H en orden de lista en las celdas disponibles (vacias) de la columna D, sabiendo que estos valores (los contenidos en las columanas desde la E hasta la H) son variables, en cuanto a que en algunos casos pueden estar distribuidos de forma diferente o no estar en todas las columnas ya mencionadas, sino, solo en una o algunas de ellas; en el siguiente link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ge-xeXMKCEV4TiqlNqnBpp2-_6N6aLi/view?usp=sharing - les comparto el libro .xlsm que estoy trabajando como prueba macro de este procedimiento, con dos hojas las cuales clasifico de forma visual con un antes y un despues del procedimiento que anteriormente describo.

He intentado obtener este resultado con la siguinete macro:

```
Sub InsertarItem()
Dim Celda As Range
Dim UltimaFila As Long, x As Long
Dim Valores(1 To 4) As Integer
Let UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
Valores(1) = 0: Valores(2) = 2: Valores(3) = 3: Valores(4) = 4
For Each Celda In Range("E3:E" & UltimaFila)
    For x = 1 To 4
        If Celda.Offset(0, Valores(x)) > "0" Or Celda.Offset(0, Valores(x)) > " " Or Celda.Offset(0, Valores(x)) > "REEMPLAZAR" Then
            If Valores(x) = 0 Then
                Celda.Offset(Valores(x) + 1, -1).Formula = "=" & Celda.Offset(0, Valores(x)).Address(0, 0)
            ElseIf Valores(x) = 2 Then
                Celda.Offset(Valores(x), -1).Formula = "=" & Celda.Offset(0, Valores(x)).Address(0, 0)
            ElseIf Valores(x) = 3 And Valores(x) = 4 Then
                Celda.Offset(Valores(x) - 1, -1).Formula = "=" & Celda.Offset(0, Valores(x)).Address(0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next Celda
End Sub
```

pero no he logrado del todo lo que pretendo, ya que al ejecutarla copia los valores pero sin tener en cuenta la celda disponible en la columna D y la distribucion de la informacion contenida en las columnas desde la E hasta la H, en el libro que les comparto en la hoja asociada al "conprocedimiendo" muestro los seis (6) casos que son los que pueden ocurrir en la tabla en orden aleatorio con el resultado deseado.

A continuacion propongo la situacion que he mencionado anteriormente en imagenes, aclarando que todos los casos que se presentan estan coloreados en razon de que estan asociados entre si, es decir, las celdas con color entre si tienen relacion en como deben resultar luego del procedimiento de copiado de valores (de los valores contenidos en las columnas desde la E hasta H) en los campos disponibles dela columna D.

Sin procedimiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con procedimiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago las siguientes aclaraciones,

- Siempre habrán los espacios suficientes para que se puedan poner o copiar los valores dispestos en las celdas E a H, ya que para esto tengo una macro especifica que me inserta filas de acuerdo a los datos contenidos en las celdas E a H, es decir, si tengo valores en las **celdas E3, F3, G3 y H3**, entonces en la columna D tendré 4 filas disponibles para poner los valores en todos los casos.
- En todos los casos siempre me va a aparecer en la primera posicion de esa misma fila de la columna D el dato (azul) de la columna F; ya que esta formulado para que así sea, de igual manera si solo hay un registro en alguna de las celdas E3, F3, G3 y **H3**, en especifico en las celdas de la **columna H** (Asociado al valor constante de la columna I = "RETIRAR" el cual posiciono como ***caso 4***) siempre me va a aparecer en la primera posicion de esa misma fila de la columna D el dato (rojo) de la columna H.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. ¿Qué problema concreto tienes? ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes he hecho la edicion de la pregunta, donde ilustro con imagenes un ejemplo de la tabla antes y despues del procedimiento que busco (tambien deje un link del libro con la macro que estoy utilizando), donde pregunto ¿como puedo lograr copiar los valores contenidos en las columnas desde la E hasta la H de manera oredenada y en la celda disponible de la columna D?, aclarando que las celdas coloreadas lo hice asi para dar a enterder la relacion que tienen entre ellas en los casos y como se deben copiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solucion  en estas lineas de codigo,

les comparto la macro a continuacion

```
Sub InsertarItem()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  Dim arr As Variant
  '
  arr = Array("F", "E", "G", "H")
  '
  For i = 3 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row
    k = i
    For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
      If Range(arr(j) & i) <> "" Then
        Range("D" & k) = Range(arr(j) & i)
        k = k + 1
      End If
    Next
    i = k - 1
  Next
  '
End Sub
```

Solo me queda pendiente el encontrar la forma en que el procedimiento no me de solo el valor en los campos de la columna D, si no mas bien un valor con referencia a las celdas que copio.